# distribution transaction lock in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions, distributed

I have some question around transaction lock in oracle database. What I have found out so far is that:

**Cause**: The time to wait on a lock in a distributed transaction has been exceeded. This time is specified in the initialization parameter `DISTRIBUTED_LOCK_TIMEOUT`.

**Action**: This situation is treated as a deadlock and the statement was rolled back. To set the time-out interval to a longer interval, adjust the initialization parameter `DISTRIBUTED_LOCK_TIMEOUT`, then shut down and restart the instance.

Some other things that I want to know in more details are things like:

1. It is mentioned that a lock in 'distributed transaction' happened. So what kind of database operation that can cause this ? Updating a record ? Selecting a record ?
2. What does 'Distributed' means anyway. I have seen this term coined all over the place, but I can't seem to deduce what it means.
3. What can we do to reduce instances of such lock ?

Comment: Oracle's online documentation is pretty good.  Answers to most questions of a general nature, such as this one, can be found in the Concepts guide - http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/toc.htm

Answer (score 3):

A distributed transaction means that you had a transaction that had two different participants.  If you are using PL/SQL, that generally implies that there are multiple databases involved.  But it may simply indicate that an application is using an external transaction coordinator in its interactions with the database.  A J2EE application, for example, might want to create a distributed transaction that covers both issuing SQL statements against a database to move $100 from account A to account B as well as the application server action of creating a JMS message for this transaction that would eventually cause an email notification of the transfer to be sent.  In this case, the application wants to ensure that the state of the middle tier matches the state of the back end.

Distributed transactions are not free.  They involve potentially quite a bit of additional overhead because, at a minimum, you need to use the [two-phase commit protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol) to verify that all the components that are part of the distributed transaction are ready to commit and to verify that they all did commit.  That involves sending a number of network packets which can be a significant fraction of the time an OLTP transaction is waiting.  Distributed transactions also cause administrative issues because you end up with cases where one participant's transaction fails after it indicated it was ready to commit or a transaction coordinator failing while various participants have open transactions.

So the first question would be whether your application actually needs distributed transactions.  Sometimes, developers find that they are accidentally requesting distributed transactions when they really aren't necessary.  If you're not sure what a distributed transaction is, it's entirely possible that you don't really need them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide [here](https://hernk.wordpress.com/2006/06/21/simulating-lock-timeout/) that will walk you through the steps to simulate an ORA-02049: timeout: distributed transaction waiting for lock if you want a better understanding of one of its causes: